# Evolution doesn't seem to be aware of my Online Accounts

Tags: 16.04, evolution

I enabled two Google accounts through System Settings -> Online Accounts, but Evolution doesn't seem to be aware of them? I mostly want calendar access. I looked at Gnome Calendar and Evolutions' calendar and I don't even see how I would add them.

The "add calendar" dialog has a "google" option but it doesn't seem to recognize that the online account is already set up.

I feel like I'm missing something super obvious here. How do I manage calendars for an account I setup through online accounts?

Comment: This used to work automatically but I am having exactly the same problem today. Google accounts don't work if you set them up through Evolution but now they are not being automatically added from Online accounts.

Comment: @Simon were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: It just started working again, I am using it in Ubuntu 16.04 powerpc now without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be sorted in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

So I guess the solution is "update your OS."